# Extracting latest version of articles from the results of a previous query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, liferay

I have the following query:

```
SELECT e_c.*, c.name, j.status, j.version, j.articleId, j.title FROM assetcategory AS c
    INNER JOIN assetentries_assetcategories AS e_c 
        ON c.categoryId = e_c.categoryId AND c.name = 'news'
    INNER JOIN assetentry AS e
        ON e.entryId = e_c.entryId
    INNER JOIN journalarticle AS j
        ON j.resourcePrimKey = e.classPK
        AND e.classNameId = (SELECT classNameId FROM classname_ WHERE value = 'com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle')
        AND j.companyId= e.companyId
WHERE j.status = 0
```

which returns all the category `news` in the `journalarticles`. From the results I need to select the most recent versions for each `articleId`. For example suppose there is an article with 4 versions, even with different title, it is the same article because it will have the same `articleId`. So therefore for each unique `articleId` I need the latest `version`. How can I do that?

Comment: Accessing Liferay's data directly through the database sooner or later might lead to the temptation to write the data by these means as well. And this has been proven to be a recipe for disaster multiple times. Just be aware that Liferay has an API that you should use, rather than dealing with the database itself. It will make your life (and upgrades in particular) so much easier. If you write to the database, all bets are off. It might work right now, but fail during future upgrades, because there's data that the upgrade routines (or the API) doesn't expect (or missing data that it expects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a join to a subquery which finds the most recent version for each article:

```
SELECT e_c.*, c.name, j1.status, j1.version, j1.articleId, j1.title
FROM assetcategory AS c
INNER JOIN assetentries_assetcategories AS e_c 
    ON c.categoryId = e_c.categoryId AND c.name = 'news'
INNER JOIN assetentry AS e
    ON e.entryId = e_c.entryId
INNER JOIN journalarticle AS j1
    ON j1.resourcePrimKey = e.classPK AND
       e.classNameId = (SELECT classNameId FROM classname_
                   WHERE value = 'com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle') AND
       j.companyId = e.companyId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT articleId, MAX(version) AS max_version
    FROM journalarticle
    WHERE status = 0
    GROUP BY articleId
) j2
    ON j1.articleId = j2.articleId AND j1.version = j2.max_version;
```

The basic idea behind the join to the subquery aliased as `j2` above is that it restricts the result set to only the most recent version of each article.  We don't necessarily have to change the rest of the query.

Comment: Dude thanks a lot man. I spent an entire day on this and you gave me in 5 mins. How do I become an expert like you?

Comment: where are do I even start. I only know the very basics. I understood the query which you gave as an answer, but I couldnt come up with it.

Comment: Search for information on querying to find the max per group.  My answer is just an application of this.